# Django: matching URL patterns to display data results in a 404

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to use the URL pattern match to display data dynamically in my template. The goal is to display data based on organization type of which I have 3: Manufacturers, Suppliers, and Distributors.

So, if the URL matches `/profiles/man_dash/**manufacturers**/`, then display data for all Manufacturers. Below is my code:

**View**

```
def man_org_list(request, member_type=None):
    member_type_map = {
        'manufacturers': 'Manufacturer',
        'suppliers': 'Supplier',
        'distributors': 'Distributor'
    }

    member_type = member_type_map.get(member_type, None)
    if member_type is None:
        raise Http404
    queryset = Organization.objects.filter(member__member_flag=1, member__member_type=member_type).order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'profiles/man_dash.html', {'object_list': queryset})
```

**Core urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('profiles/', include('profiles.urls'))
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.org_list, name='org_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.org_details, name='org_details'),
    url(r'^man_dash/<str:member_type>/', views.man_org_list, name='man_org_list')
]
```

**Code block I want to display:**

```
{% for org in object_list %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ org.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ org.org_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ org.org_type }}</td>
        {% for member in org.member.all %}
        <td>{{ member.member_flag }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for c_score in org.c_score.all %}
        <td>{{ c_score.completeness_score }}%</td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td><a href="{% url 'org_details' org.id %}" target="_blank">View</a></td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

For some reason, I keep getting the error:

```
The current path, profiles/man_dash/manufacturers/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: have you added the profile urls to your core app urls?

Comment: @abidibo Yes. All other url patterns are working just fine. I think the issue might be somewhere in the view.

Comment: well, that kind of error shouldn't be triggered from inside the view

Comment: @abidibo hmmm... I even tried to replace man_dash/<str:member_type>/ with man_dash/manufacturers/ to see if it works but no luck.

Comment: you'd better post also your core app urls.py and the stack trace

Comment: I added the core urls.py how do a do stack trace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184701/discussion-between-abidibo-and-user3088202).

Comment: You have only included some of the error message *The current path...* in your question. The full error message will show you all the URL patterns Django tried.

Comment: Changing to it path() worked. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url(r'^man_dash/<str:member_type>/', views.man_org_list, name='man_org_list')
```

You are mixing up the old and new URL syntax here. `<str:member_type>` belongs in a `path()`, but `r'^...'` is a regex which belongs in `url()`.

Try changing it to:

```
path('man_dash/<str:member_type>/', views.man_org_list, name='man_org_list')
```

Comment: That gives me the same result as the other way.

Comment: You haven't shown the full error message, so I don't have any other suggestions.